# Asp net core serialize resx file and return in in ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core

I'm using a lot of jquery in my project and i was wondering if it's possible to return the relevant(based on current language) `.resx` file (as a json) through an ajax call so that i can further use those translations across my page.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
 [HttpGet("getTranslations")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetTranslations()
 {
    return relevant resx file;
 }
```

It would return something like:

```
{
"key":"value",
"key1":"value1",
 etc
}
```

And then i could use those across my page whenever i need a translation.

I hope this question is not complete nonsense, it's just something that i figured should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no need to read the .resx file. You should better use resource manager and get whole list of localized resources as an object, and then serialize it. Try something like this:

```
[HttpGet("getTranslations")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTranslations()
{
   var resources = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true); //Sget resources for specified culture

   var resDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   foreach (var r in resources)
   {
      resDict.Add(r.Key.ToString(), r.Value);
   }
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resDict); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll be going this route most likely. I just need to find a way to get this working in asp.net core.